# I want to find a mode for each group of dataframes within the element of a list, and write the result as a new column

Tags: r

I have a list called "data". It consists of 10 elements (lists), each having different number of elements (lists), such as

> ```
> lengths(data)
> ```

[1] 26 33  3 20 22 21 17 18 12 29

Thus, the first element of our list consists of 26 elements, the second of 33, and so on ... Each of these elements are dataframes ("tibbles"), with 6 columns (first four being integers, fifth logical, and the last character), for instance

> ```
> colnames(data[[1]][[1]])
> ```

[1] "width"  "height" "x"      "y"      "space"  "text"

Although the structure of dataframes (columns) is consistent in and outside of the groups, the number of rows differs for each dataframe even within the group.

I want to find a mode "height" for the dataframes grouped within the same element.

Thus, there is common mode for 26 dataframes within the first element and so on. In other words, I want to group the data for 26 dataframes within the first element, calculate the mode, and then write result as a new column to each of the dataframes so that I could perform different operations for rows with height above, below, and equal to mode.

**This is what I figured out so far, although it is not correct it should produce the same result in most of the cases:**

```
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}

mode <- lapply(data, function(x) lapply(lapply(x, '[[', 
           'height'), getmode)) # find    mode height for each
                                # paper and each page
mode2 <- lapply(mode, function (x) getmode(x)) 
                          # find mode for each paper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option where we loop over the outer list with `map`, then bind the inner list elements to a single data with `bind_rows` (from `dplyr`) creating a column `grp`, apply the `getmode` on the combined 'height' column to create a new column and then split the dataset by the 'grp' column

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(data, ~ bind_rows(.x, .id = 'grp') %>% 
    mutate(Mode = getmode(height)) %>%
    group_split(grp, .keep = FALSE))
```

---

Or loop over the `list` with `lapply`, loop over the inner list with `sapply`, extract the 'height' from individual inner list elements, apply the `getmode` and return a vector of mode values on which the `getmode` is applied again.  Then loop over the inner list and create a new column with the mode value we got

```
lapply(data, function(x) {
   mode <- getmode(sapply(x, function(y) getmode(y$height)))
   lapply(x, function(y) cbind(y, mode))
 })
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
 data1 <- replicate(26, head(mtcars) %>% mutate(height = rnorm(6)), simplify = FALSE)
 data2 <- replicate(33, head(iris) %>% mutate(height = rnorm(6)), simplify = FALSE)
 data <- list(data1, data2)
```

Comment: I have no idea how you solved it so fast but both seem to be working. thank you